# Solve the heat equation - by splitting up the second order derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I tried to solve the heat equation here, but I am not sure this works out.

We have

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=4\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}~,  \qquad 0<x<\pi\,,~t>0
\end{equation}

I.C. are

\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y) = 0 \\    
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\pi,y) = 0   \\
u(x,0)= \cos5x
\end{cases}

So we know that

\begin{align}
&fu_x=f_xg \\
&u_{xx}=f_{xx}g \\
&u_y=g_yf
\end{align}

So the equation by separation of variables is:

\begin{equation}
f_{xx}g-4g_yf=0
\end{equation}

But since we can write

\begin{equation}
f_{xx}g=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f\bigg)g
\end{equation}

and I.C.s can be written as:

\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}f(0)g(y) = 0 \\    
  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}f(0)g(y) = 0   \\
  f(x)g(0)= \cos5x
\end{cases}

Then we can substitute  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(0)g(y)=0$ right into the equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(0)g\bigg)-4g_yf=0
\end{equation}

and that will zero out the first term, and we are left with

\begin{equation}
g_yf=0
\end{equation}

Knowing that $f(x)= \cos5x$, we have at $u(x,0)$:

\begin{equation}
g_y \cos 5x=0
\end{equation}

which unfortunately, has only the trivial solution. Is there any way to use this simplification to solve this system? If not, what is the better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

We can guess that $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ Then we get

$$u_{xx} = 4u_y = X^{''}(x)*Y(y) = 4Y^{'}(y)X(x)$$

From there, we isolate the functions to get

$$\frac{X^{''}(x)}{X(x)}=4\frac{Y^{'}(y)}{Y(y)}$$

However, a function of x can only equal a function of y if both functions are constant. Let's call this function $-\lambda$

Then

$$\frac{X^{''}(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda$$

$$4\frac{Y^{'}(y)}{Y(y)}=-\lambda$$

See if you can solve from here!

Comment: Got it, please check that typo of $u_{xx}$ instead of $u_xx$

Comment: Done, thanks for the feedback!